# Deploying JSF Website to Azure?

Tags: azure, jakarta-ee

I have created a JSF website that uses another EJB project that contains JPA Entities and Session Beans. Of course, they both use the same EAR.

My question is, is it possible to publish this EAR to Azure?

I am using Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software v9.1

[EDIT]:
Besides Azure (since the option to create a WAS VM on Azure isn't free), is there any other free option to publish a web application of this kind?

Comment: Well, you need a Java application server to deploy the EAR. As you're using RAD, WebSphere is the obvious choice. There is a VM available for [WAS on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partners/msopentech/was-8-5/). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @XSurgent I am not quite sure what I'm looking for, so as far as I know anything I can use to deploy the EAR, and for this EAR to be live and accessible then this is what I'm looking for. Kind of like deploying a web application from Visual Studio to Azure, but using a Java application's EAR instead. 
Do you know if this is free to use?